# Format for inserting time

Tags: mysql

i need help with the best data-type and format needed to insert time into a table.

for example i have a table FLIGHT and in that table i want to insert flightArrival  and flight departure to look exactly like this

```
flightArrival                    flightDepature
7:00AM                          2:00PM
```

what format would i need to get this?

I used the datatype 'time' it does not work on my SQL. so I tried the TIMESTAMP data type and used this format `TO_TIMESTAMP('07:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss')` and instead it gave me something else which i have posted a screenshot of below.

[image]

what datatype and formart can i use to insert into my table to give me this exact output?

used the TIME data type and it didnt work at all then i tried TIMESTAMP  TO_TIMESTAMP('07:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss') to try input a time but it gave me a different output. instead of 07:00AM it was giving me 01-JUL-23 07.00.00.000000000 AM

Comment: Don't do that.  Store the actual date (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) in the table and then manipulate it to look like you want in the output layer.  Something like DATE_FORMAT(arrivalDate, '%h:%i%p').  You can test in mySQL with SELECT NOW(), DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%h:%i%p') to see how it will output.

Comment: Hi Chrris thanks for the reply. Any change you can help me type out how i should do it? still pretty new with SQL. For example what data type do i use and how to i write the formart which youve sent while inserting into the table?

Comment: Make the field either DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.  Which one and how to insert will depend on your source data.  Can you give me an example of how the dates are given in the data you want to insert?  To be clear, you DONT want to make the data look like that in the table, you want it either as a real date or a real timestamp.  And then when you select data OUT of the table, that's when you make it look how you want.

Comment: so i created a table called flight and while creating the table, i added EstimatedDeparture and EstimetedArrival. Now what next is to insert into the flight table. Im sorry if im not quite getting what you are explaning im quite new..... This is how the time comes out>>>> 01-JUL-23 07.00.00.000000000 AM.  But i need it to be like this >>>> 07:00AM

Comment: I'm not asking what the data in the table looks like, because the process you described (using TO_TIMESTAMP) doesn't seem like the right way to go about it.  What I'm asking is how the data looked BEFORE you inserted it.  What do the dates in the source data look like?

Comment: This is actually something that you should probably have included in the original question: database structure (not a screenshot of the db, either), the source data you're using, and what you have tried.  Look at this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: There is no source data i am the one that is meant to provide an actual time ill post my code below.......                                                                                                         
 CREATE TABLE Flight (
  FlightID VARCHAR2(10), 
  Origin VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  Destination  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  EstimatedDeparture TIMESTAMP,
  EstimatedArrival TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT RoutePK PRIMARY KEY(FlightID)
);

Comment: This is how i inserted it 

INSERT INTO Flight (FlightID, Origin, Destination, EstimatedDeparture, EstimatedArrival) 
VALUES ('GFK576', 'Captown', 'Pretotia', TO_TIMESTAMP('07:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss'), TO_TIMESTAMP('14:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss'));

Comment: 14:00:00 isn't a date.  What are the actual dates in the raw data?

Comment: When you say "i'm meant to provide actual time" based on WHAT?  I assume at some point you will have a list of flights with departure and arrival dates.  What will that look like?

Comment: 29th July 2022 is the date given

Comment: I would combine the date and time fields into one in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and store it as a DATETIME field. This allows for easier searching and handling of date ranges that cross a date boundary, for instance, searching for flights +- 4 hours from midnight.  Then you take the date field and extract the part you need, if you want the hour: DATE_FORMAT(arrivalDate, '%h:%i%p').  Let me set up a fiddle that will demonstrate the insert and outputs.

Comment: I assume at some point you will have a list of flights with departure and arrival dates                                         I wasnt given any data just this>>>>>>>>>>> - The GFK576 route is from Cape town to Perotia and has an estimated time of departure of 0700 and estimated time of arrival of 1400.  So i am meant to insert that and then populate the table with random data just like that

Comment: Does this data only cover one day?  And is this a study question and not a real world example?

Comment: It is a study question. i was given that for the date 29th July 2022. Then insert different data just like like that so it comes out like a real world output

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle and tell me if it helps.  If it does, I'll turn it into an answer with some explanations and some information on why you might choose a DATETIME vs TIMESTAMP vs two separate fields, DATE and TIME.  It depends on your use case, and this is a textbook question, but I'll explain some of the considerations:  https://dbfiddle.uk/Uo8jmbug

Comment: This is simply perfect and exactly how i want it to look but for some reason mySQL does not support the DATETIME data type. So now i dont know what else to do.

Comment: That fiddle is implemented in mySQL.  mySQL absolutely does support DATETIME: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

you should call [`date_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format your datetime data as required.

Hint: Take a look at `%r` flag.

Comment: Hello sorry i dont quite understand what you mean.  First thing i did was to create the flight table by using this>>>>>>>>   CREATE TABLE Flight ( FlightID VARCHAR2(10), Origin VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, Destination VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, EstimatedDeparture TIMESTAMP, EstimatedArrival TIMESTAMP, CONSTRAINT RoutePK PRIMARY KEY(FlightID) );

Comment: This i tried in insert into it using this >>>>>>>>>>>>  INSERT INTO Flight (FlightID, Origin, Destination, EstimatedDeparture, EstimatedArrival) VALUES ('GFK576', 'Captown', 'Pretotia', TO_TIMESTAMP('07:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss'), TO_TIMESTAMP('14:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss'));

Comment: But on the EstimatedDeparture and arrival column, it is not outputing '7:00AM and 2:00PM'..  Instead its is outputing 01-JUL-23 07.00.00.000000000 AM

Comment: you're conflating the input part with the select part.  Input a datetime in whatever format, then select the datetime out in the format you choose.  keep with it, you'll get it